# Landscape and desktop view to make different in media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to make the landscape view in 7inches ipad different than the desktop view when the desktop resolution is same as landscape. I am using the following for lanscape, but dont want this styling to occur on desktop when desktop matches the width of lanscape:

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)  and (max-device-height : 768px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/*style goes here*/
}
```

Please help as I need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **head.js**: http://headjs.com/

It's setting a bunch of useful css-classes to the head-element of you page.

```
<html class="js no-mobile desktop no-ie root-section w-1318 gt-240 
gt-320 gt-480 gt-640 gt-768 gt-800 gt-1024 gt-1280 lt-1440 lt-1680 
lt-1920 no-portrait landscape gradient rgba opacity textshadow 
multiplebgs boxshadow borderimage borderradius cssreflections 
csstransforms csstransitions no-touch no-retina fontface domloaded">
```

**The CSS-Classes you need are:**

- desktop / no-desktop
- mobile / no-mobile

and even the sizes (they refresh on resize):

- gt-768 / lt-768
- gt-1024 / lt-1024